# Find a power series. centered at $x=-1$

Tags: power-series

I'm trying to find a power series, centered at $x=-1$

What do I have to do for next step?

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2x-3} = \frac{1}{2(x+1)-2-3} = \frac{1}{5}[\frac{1}{\frac{2}{5}(x+1)-1}]$

Comment: Do you know the power series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ ?

Comment: @Teddy Yes. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$

Comment: If you substitute $t = \frac{2}{5}(x+1)$, you get the form I mentioned, in $t$.

Comment: @Teddy how do I substitute $t$ into $\frac{1}{1-x}$? I have tried, but i can't. so I have asked this question. $

Comment: @Teddy Oh, wait! Never mind! I solved. Thank you.

Comment: Substituting $t = \frac{2}{5}(x+1)$, your expression equals
$ \frac{1}{5}[\frac{1}{t-1}] = -\frac{1}{5}[\frac{1}{1-t}] = -\frac{1}{5}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{5} t^n =...$

Comment: @Teddy Thank you for help, Teddy!:-)